# SDWebImage setImageWithURL return empty outside any other method than cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, sdwebimage

I am using SDWwbImage, wich i download from here:

> https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

I tested in the method: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and everything works fine, here is my code:

```
[cell.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.imageUrl]];
```

Now i need to call an image outside this method (eg: `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, `viewDidLoad`), and i always get no image, here is my code:

```
UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[test setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:categories.imageUrl]];
NSLog(@"height: %f", test.image.size.height);
```

Is it disallowed to use `setImageWithURL` anywhere? how can i solve this?

EDITED

I tried to add the completion block to know when the download is finished and refresh the uitablevew, here is my code:

```
UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [test setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.imageUrl]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher_57@2x.png"]
                              completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                  counterY++;
                                  if (counterY == counterX) {
                                      NSLog(@"reloading");
                                      [self.tableView reloadData];
                                  }
        }];
```

But only the first time the controller is loaded, this doesnt work. Every time after this everything is fine.It looks like something cancel de download the first time.

Comment: `setImageWithURL` actually does the magic of downloading the image asynchronously, so the image is not immediately available.  You'll need to make other arrangements, or check the `SDWebImage` documentation for some way of being notified when the image is actually available.

Comment: Not sure what you have going on with counterX and Y, but that's definitely suspect.